# python thread inside a loop causing runtime error ( join() not waiting for thread to end?)

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def s_process():
    print('***********************************************')
    ##time.sleep(2)
    print('###############################################')
    ##time.sleep(2)
    return

a = Thread(target=s_process)

while(True):
    a.start()
    a.join()
    a.start()
    a.join()
```

why is this code causing an error

```
***********************************************
###############################################
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 16, in <module>
    a.start()
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

shouldn't join() wait till the thread is finished. and if I have misunderstood how join() works how should I wait for the thread to finish without using a timeout

Comment: Change your code to this
**
while(True):
    a = Thread(target=s_process)
    a.start()
    a.join()
**

Comment: The error isn't on the `join` line, it's on the `start` line. It seems self-explanatory to me: don't call `start` twice on the same object. Create a new thread object if you have to.

Comment: You are defining only 1 thread, `a` and you already started plus called its `join()` method. Cant start it again!

Comment: Is it safe to create so many thread objects? would they mess with the memory usage ? or do they get cleaned up after finishing

Comment: So threads use the same memory footprint, where as processes get their own footprint. The Global Interpreter Lock (or GIL) allows only one thread at a time to execute Python bytecode (unless its I/O and then _most_ of it bypasses the GIL). I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil) and [that](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf) for some more in-depth knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def s_process():
    print('***********************************************')
    ##time.sleep(2)
    print('###############################################')
    ##time.sleep(2)
    return

while(True):
    a = Thread(target=s_process)
    a.start()
    a.join()
    del a           #deletes a
```

Comment: Is it safe to create so many thread objects? would they mess with the memory usage ? or do they get cleaned up after finishing

Comment: **del a ** will cleanup

Comment: but this method creates 1 thread at a time. What's the point of creating 1 thread then? why not call `s_process` directly?

Answer (score 0):

To start multiple threads, build a list of `threading.Thread` objects and iterate their `start()` and `join()` methods using a `for` loop like so:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def s_process():
    print('***********************************************')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('###############################################')
    time.sleep(2)
    return

# list comprehension that creates 2 threading.Thread objects
threads = [Thread(target=s_process) for x in range(0, 2)]

# starts thread 1
# joins thread 1
# starts thread 2
# joins thread 2
for thread in threads:
    try:
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # std Python exception
        continue # moves to next thread iterable
```

**Edit:** Inlcuded `try/except` for `KeyboardInterrupt` and tested with general use Ctrl+X+C.

Comment: I need to loop the same code without getting interrupted in the middle of execution form KeyboardInterrupt